# 32 bit Java won't install on my x64 desktop

Tags: java

I've been trying to run OldSchool RuneScape on my desktop and whenever I try any of the launch options that Jagex provides, nothing happens. I've had extensive talks with their staff and it's to the point where they don't know what's wrong, but I have a pretty good idea.

Whenever I try to install 32 bit Java (Online or Offline), I get "java error code 1603". The official help page for this error on the Java website says that they don't know what causes this error, but have two possible solutions. I have tried both, they don't work.

I do have x64 Java installed and working, but OSRS requires x86. So, what do?

Side note, I know this might not be the right place for this question. If not, please redirect me to the right spot.

EDIT: I've managed to install previous versions of x86 Java (6 and 7), but they throw this error https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfSKT.png before "confirming" that Java has been installed correctly. Despite this confirmation, still nothing works. I'm in talks with the RS mods again and we're working through more confirmations. If I get this working before someone else suggests here, I'll update this again.

SOLUTION: I used an uninstall tool called JavaRa to remove lingering files as well as removing anything Java-related from System PATH, then re-installed Java. Now it works. Don't understand why, but I'm not questioning it.

Comment: https://java.com/en/download/help/error_1603.xml

Comment: That is the official help page I mentioned, where I tried the workarounds and they didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[check here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3671329?start=0)

1 Close the installer when you see Java error 1603. (It has installed a bunch of files, but exits prematurely.)

2 Open `javacpl.exe from C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_XX\bin` (or for **x64,** `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_XX\bin)` where XX is the update number.

3 Uncheck **Enable Java content in the browser** on security tab and click OK to close Java control panel

4 Retry installing Java. It usually succeeds for this time.

5 Open `javacpl.exe` again (see step #2)

6 Check Enable Java content in browser on security tab and click OK to close Java control panel

7 If it still fails, try uninstalling `windows update KB2918614`, then reboot and try these steps again

Comment: Ooh thanks, I didn't find this thread. Don't have time to tinker with this today, but I'll give it a shot tomorrow.

Comment: Sadly these steps didn't work for me. I'll take a look at the thread that you linked and see if anything in there will help.

Comment: googled it and got solutions , so posted here , thought it might help

Comment: It was worth a shot, and I appreciate the help.

Comment: I've edited my question with the solution I eventually found.